# Can I stack an older dryer on top of a new washer?

Tags: washing-machine

I have a Maytag 5000 series (med5500vw1) dryer that still works. I want to stack it on top of a Maytag washer (mhw5630hw).

Please let me know if it can be done and can I use my same stacking kit and hose?

Comment: what do you mean by same stacking kit (same as what)

Comment: A stacking kit presumably consists of support and attachment hardware. It's a safety concern to not connect the two appliances.

Comment: The Maytag stacking kit is very specific to certain models.  Look at the documentation and/or just try it by following the instructions that came with the kit.  If it doesn't work, there are generic stacking kits available on line and at hardware stores.  What do you mean about the hose?  What does that have to do with stacking?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [blog](https://www.maytag.com/blog/washers-and-dryers/how-to-stack-washer-and-dryer.html) by Maytag on it.

The MED5500 is stackable

> In general it is possible to directly stack a dryer and washing machine directly on top of each other. This only works with front loading models. However, it is advisable to use a fitting accessory to do so. This will prevent the machines from vibrating and falling off and also prevents damage to the bottom machine.

From [manuall.co.uk](https://manuall.co.uk/maytag-med5500fc-dryer/)

And so is MHW5630

> Maytag MHW5630HW Stackable machines are ideal if you have limited space as you could stack a tumble dryer on top of a washing machine.

From [versus.com](https://versus.com/en/maytag-mhw5630hw/stackable)